# How to check the radio button is clickable or not in cypress

Tags: cypress

I need to check whether the radio button is clickable or not. In some scenarios this radio button is clickable but in some scenarios, the user is not able to click the radio button.

The cursor is not allowed in the not clickable scenario.

Can someone help me for this?

I have attached screenshots below.

I have tried many this but not worked.

checkSkipBtnClickable(){

```
    const checkSkipButton = cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .ant-radio-wrapper')
  

 }
```

[Cursor is not allowed to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSo7Z.png)

[Cursor is allowed to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXtpG.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc7KZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you a true/false value in an alias called `checkSkipButton`

```js
cy.contains('h3', 'Skip')
  .parent()
  .then($el => $el.css('cursor') === 'not-allowed')
  .as('checkSkipButton')

cy.get('@checkSkipButton').then(checkSkipButton => {
  if (checkSkipButton) {
    ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I got:

```
cy.contains('h3', 'Skip')
      .parent()
      .then($el => $el.css('cursor') === 'not-allowed')
      .as('checkSkipButton')

      cy.get('@checkSkipButton').then(checkSkipButton => {
          if (checkSkipButton) {
            cy.log("Skip is not available")
          }
          else{
              cy.log("Skip is available")
          }
      })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).